Unable to move windows on Sonoma using private APIs in Swift
I'm trying to move windows around from other spaces to the current window and have wasted many hours not understanding why nothing is being moved..
I've tried various applications (hardcoding some screens now to test). I ensure window level is 0 and various other things, but the key thing is that the private API is not migrating the window. Common libs on the market today are using these calls on this Mac release, but I'm worried there is an additional step in the flow I'm missing.
Demo repo: https://github.com/Schachte/mac-os-graphics
I've tried thread sleeps between windows, etc. The main snippet is this:
static func addInitialRunningApplicationsWindows() {
    let cgsMainConnectionId = CGSMainConnectionID()
    let otherSpaces = [UInt64(213)]
    print("Other spaces found: \(otherSpaces)")
    
    guard otherSpaces.count > 0 else {
        print("No other spaces found")
        return
    }
    
    let windowsOnCurrentSpace = getWindowsInSpace([currentSpaceId])
    print("Windows on current space: \(windowsOnCurrentSpace)")
    
    let windowsOnOtherSpaces = getWindowsInSpace(otherSpaces)
    print("Windows on other spaces: \(windowsOnOtherSpaces)")
    
    let windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces = Array(Set(windowsOnOtherSpaces).subtracting(windowsOnCurrentSpace))
    print("Windows to move: \(windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces)")
    
    guard windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces.count > 0 else {
        print("No windows to move")
        return
    }
    
    // Split windows into chunks to avoid overwhelming the API
    let chunkSize = 5
    let windowChunks = stride(from: 0, to: windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces.count, by: chunkSize).map {
        Array(windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, windowsOnlyOnOtherSpaces.count)])
    }
    
    for chunk in windowChunks {
        print("Processing chunk of \(chunk.count) windows")
        
        // First add windows to the current space
        CGSAddWindowsToSpaces(cgsMainConnectionId,
                             chunk as NSArray,
                             [currentSpaceId] as NSArray)
        
        // Give the system a moment to process
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        
        // Then remove from other spaces
        for spaceId in otherSpaces {
            CGSRemoveWindowsFromSpaces(cgsMainConnectionId,
                                     chunk as NSArray,
                                     [spaceId] as NSArray)
            
            // Give the system a moment to process
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        }
        
        // Verify the move for this chunk
        let windowsStillOnOtherSpaces = getWindowsInSpace(otherSpaces)
        let unmovedInChunk = chunk.filter { windowsStillOnOtherSpaces.contains($0) }
        
        if unmovedInChunk.count > 0 {
            print("Warning: Failed to move \(unmovedInChunk.count) windows in current chunk")
            
            // Try alternative method for unmoved windows
            for windowId in unmovedInChunk {
                if canMoveWindow(windowId) {
                    print("Attempting alternative move for window \(windowId)")
                    CGSMoveWindowsToManagedSpace(cgsMainConnectionId,
                                               [windowId] as NSArray,
                                               currentSpaceId)
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Output
5
Other spaces found: [213]
Windows on current space: [115, 99, 98, 94, 26, 100, 25, 27, 24, 22, 38, 12159, 10, 116, 942, 12493, 12557, 13406]
Windows on other spaces: [13749, 16723, 13747, 116, 13328]
Windows to move: [16723, 13749, 13747, 13328]
Processing chunk of 4 windows
Warning: Failed to move 4 windows in current chunk
Attempting alternative move for window 16723
Warning: Total failed moves: 4 windows
Unmoved window IDs: [16723, 13749, 13747, 13328]
5

Using inspiration from https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos
Thread sleeps, different windows, running as root, disabling SIP

IIRC much of the CGS APIs are locked down through an 'ownership' model. Apps only 'own' their own windows and are only allowed to move those. The Dock process is a 'universal owner' and can manipulate all the windows. But IIRC, the Universal ownership is locked through a special entitlement, and when you give your own app that entitlement macOS will just not run it. The only way that I know of to manipulate windows is to use the Accessibiliy API. Which is slow and restrictive but it works.

Actually, IIRC there were also some older, lesser known APIs that could be used to bring a window to the front and stuff programmatically, but they were quite restrictive as well. I don't remember the names but I remember they were really old and deprecated for years but still worked.

Actually, only certain interactions with window are locked down through the 'ownership' model IIRC. I think moving windows is among the forbidden things but I'm not entirellyyy sure anymore.
